# Difference between "It's" and "Are" to start a sentence

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between "It's guys like you" and "Are guys like you"?

It seems to be a very silly question but I don't understand it. I hope someone helps me understand.

Comment: One is a statement, the other is a question - and are barely comparable. You may find it helpful to post on English Language Learners - a sister site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a question and the other a statement, but both are frequently the beginning of sentences that share the same sentiment.

1. It's guys like you who make my life hell.
2. Are guys like you going to make my life hell?
3. It's guys like you who fuck things up.
4. Are guys like you going to fuck things up?

They are both the beginning of sentences that will unfold to reveal negative consequences for the person saying them. Growing up in New Jersey, I heard these phrases daily. They are somewhat idiomatic, like the language on the Sopranos. Short, no nonsense words, mostly one syllable. Tough guy words and phrases.